# Get the value from TextIput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I want to be able to retrieve the value of the text after the user presses enter/return.

I tried the following ...

```
class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text:''
        }
    }

    callTextSubmit = (val) => {
        console.log('callTextSubmit ', val);
    };

    render() {              
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    onSubmitEditing={(text) => this.callTextSubmit(text)}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
            </View>
        )
  }
}
```

This returns the following... from the console log.

```
Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}
>[[Handler]]:Object
>[[Target]]:Class
>[[IsRevoked]]:false
```

I want to access the value from the text input, is there a workaround to this? Thank you

Comment: The argument for the `onSubmitEditing` handler is the event. Could you not just use the state variable? `console.log('callTextSubmit ', this.state.text);`

Comment: The callback, onChangeText is an event handler, accepts a synthetic event not a text value.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I just wanted to replace the `onChangeText` so it doesnt call everytime I type a letter. I wanted to set the state after I click enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for the `onSubmitEditing` handler is the event, not the current input.

Since you set the state variable `text` each time the `TextInput` is changed, you can just use the `text` variable in your state instead.

```
callTextSubmit = () => {
  console.log('callTextSubmit ', this.state.text);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But for some reason `onChangeText` is called each letter i type. Is there a way to only set the state after I press enter?

Comment: @SGhaleb Great! You might be able to use [`onKeyPress` and figure out if the keypress was the key you want](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onkeypress). However, it is desired to run `onChangeText` on each letter you type, otherwise `value={this.state.text}` will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using this line to add the TextInput's value to state

```
 onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
```

The reasonable way would be to get the value from state on your onPress function on a Button (TouchableOpacity/TouchableHighlight) added to your View like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>console.log(this.state.text)}>
  <Text>
    Enter
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is code for your Component

```
class HomePage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text:''
    }
}

callTextSubmit = () => {
    console.log(console.log(this.state.text));
};

render() {              
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                value={this.state.text}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>console.log(this.state.text)}>
               <Text>
                   Enter
               </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
```

}

Comment: you can replace that with `onPress={()=>this.callTextSubmit}`

Comment: Yeah, i just realized. Sorry, not focused. Thank you for this.